# Article accepted for publication by the managing editor of Taylor & Francis Journal

Tags: publications, journals

I received notification that my article was accepted for publication by the managing editor of Taylor & Francis journal. But when I previously looked at the site, I found that my article has been removed from the manuscript sent to journal section. In any case, it has been in this situation for 3 months, and only today I received the notification of acceptance of my article from the publishing director. Is this normal?

Comment: What's your concern? The timeline?

Comment: Yes, the publishing director sent me a message that my article had been accepted, but on the site the status of my article did not change to acceptance, not to mention that he told me that the publishing process would take a year.